# Debian cron Job Not Working Correctly

Tags: debian, cron, python

I am running Debian 12, and trying to use `crontab` to execute a Python script to retrieve some files from an Artifactory repository periodically.

I am running this job on a separate user account under `www` user. I edited the crontab using `crontab -e`

The command are as follow:

```
# Cron
0 * * * *  /path/to/py/venv/python3 /path/to/py/script.py && chown -R user:group /path/to/resource

# Command
/path/to/py/venv/python3 /path/to/py/script.py && chown -R user:group /path/to/resource
```

Based on `sudo journalctl -u cron` the job seemed to be running. I also created a separate job `0 * * * * date >> ~/clock.txt` as test. Both seemed(?) to be executing. But the Python script that supposed to retrieve the file did not write anything new to the directory I set (the date and time did not change).

I tried executing the command directly by copy and pasting it, and it worked fine and wrote the new files. Does cron need anything special to have the script execute correctly?

Comment: Are you sure that your 'www' user has the necessary permissions to write the files? Why do you think it is going to be able to perform 'chown' to 'user'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard recommendation is to add your command in script and add set of your home environment:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

source /path/to/your/home/directory/.bashrc
/path/to/py/venv/python3 /path/to/py/script.py && chown -R user:group /path/to/resource
```

and create your cron like:

```
0 * * * *  /path/to/above/script
```

Change the filenames (`bash` related) if you use different shell

Comment: thank you @Romeo, i will try this and see

Comment: i set up the script for the cron job and it works fine now, thank you @Romeo! is there a reason why it doesn't work just using the raw command?

Comment: @YTKme, the reason is (IMHO) your python script need some environment variables you do not get when run in `cron`. By design `cron` environment is very limited.